# Allow all in firewall rules on a deployment manager jinja template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I checked the [documentation][1]

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls and what I saw is that whether allow or deny, you can only specify ports and protocol but not "allow all" like what you can do in the portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Deployment Manager, you can create a firewall rule to allow/deny traffic on all protocols/ports for example like this:

```
resources:
- name: a-firewall-rule
  type: compute.v1.firewall
  properties:
    sourceRanges: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    allowed:
    - IPProtocol: all
```

I've tested it on my side and it does work like "Allow all" in the Dev Console, although it isn't properly documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls). I'll file a documentation update request to mention that the "all" value is actually accepted.

Comment: I'm talking about `allow all`

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get your question at first. I've updated my answer with the correct info.

Comment: Oh! Never thought that `all` can be used